# drupal: [title] token... not filtered?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using path auto module to automatically stores images in the projects subfolder. I'm using the [title] token and I had a unpleasent surprise: the title "abc / dce", creates 2 folders.

I was not expecting this because in the pattern descrition, [title] is clearly distinguished by [title-raw].

```
[title] Node title
[title-raw] Unfiltered node title. WARNING - raw user input.
```

So, how can I fix this issue, I would like to use the title I have in the url "abc-dce"

thanks

Comment: How do you use "path auto module to automatically stores images in the projects subfolder"? (Pathauto creates paths (URLs), but does not store anything in folders) Could you explain a bit more how you do this?

Comment: combined with CCK fields. So yes, it doesn't store itself, it specifies in which folders to store the files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These tokens aren't defined by Pathauto, but by the Token module. If you want a token that will give you a stripped down version of the node title, you can create it using the [hooks provided by Token](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/token). The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804781/in-drupal-how-to-change-the-values-passed-to-pathauto) may also help.

Comment: mhm, I cannot understand where I should place token_replace to replace a module. Is there a complete tutorial somewhere to hook modules ? I read some drupal doc but it is confusing :(

Comment: so, hooking modules = developing a complete new module ? thanks for link

Comment: Yeah, the idea is to create custom modules that will imlpement Drupal hooks to change some feature or implement a new one. This link explaing this better: http://api.drupal.org/api/group/hooks

Answer (score 2):

You can also work with the punctuation settings of the pathauto module to deal with the / character before it causes problems.

Comment: sorry, where are the pathauto settings ? I cannot find them

Comment: They are under 'URL Aliases' in the admin menu - admin/build/path/pathauto

Comment: oh ok, I've checked these settings, I didn't know it was path auto settings, since it is written URL alia in the menu. So, the problem with these settings is that there is not "/" in the Punctuation settings!! Only back-slash...